# Packaging a build-tools-only package

Tags: nuget

I am building a package with build tools only: a `.prop` and a `.target` files, and a dll with MSBuild tasks. I specified these files to be placed into the `build` folder in the `<file>` section of the nuspec file:

```
<files>
  <file src="bin\Release\Acme.Build.Foo.dll" target="build" />
  <file src="MSBuild\Acme.Build.Foo.props"   target="build" />
  <file src="MSBuild\Acme.Build.Foo.targets" target="build" />
</files>
```

The nuspec file `Acme.Build.Foo.nuspec` is placed beside the `Acme.Build.Foo.csproj`.

If I use `nuget pack Acme.Build.Foo.csproj`, the dll file gets also packaged into the `lib/` folder of the package, and added as a fererence when adding the package to the target project.

If I would use `nuget pack Acme.Build.Foo.nuspec`, I'd lose the niceties of keyword expansion, as `$id$` etc.

Can I have the best of both? Is it possible to (1) prevent project output from going into `lib/.../` automatically or (2) if not, at the least prevent that file from being added as a reference to the consuming project?

I am using the apparently the latest NuGet 3.2.0.10516.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-tool` option. So all other files are placed in `tools` folder.

```
nuget pack Acme.Build.Foo.csproj -tool
```